# How to add pciutils package in yocto AGL?

Tags: yocto, pci-e, r-car

I have built Yocto AGL(6.0.0) image for RCar-salvator-xs board and flashed its hyperflash memory.
Now, I want to perform PCIe related investigation, for that I want to use lspci command.
But, After ligging in as a root in flashed AGL image and executing **lspci** command it gives **command not found**.

How can I include pciutils in AGL source code and build it to use lspci command.

I am new to Yocto and AGL.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can add `IMAGE_INSTALL += pciutils` or `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = pciutils` in `conf/local.conf` or in your image recipe.

Comment: Thank you Parthiban for reply. I tried adding it in local.conf but I am getting error while bitbake build ERROR: ParseError at /home/cac32793/workspace_agl/build/conf/local.conf:2: unparsed line: 'IMAGE_INSTALL += pciutils' Can Please tell me in which meta-layer and .bb file I have to add this.

Comment: I will copy this as answer now

Comment: Dear Parthiban san, Could you help me in the above comment problem?

Comment: I have missed the double quotes across the string. Check the answer now. You can add in local.conf or image recipe. What is the image recipe which you are trying to build?

Comment: I am building agl-demo-platform

Comment: https://git.automotivelinux.org/AGL/meta-agl-demo/tree/recipes-platform/images/agl-demo-platform.bb?h=master#n13 You can add "pciutils" in Line 14

Comment: got it .Thank you very much Parthiban san.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "pciutils"
```

or

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "pciutils"
```

in `conf/local.conf` or in your image recipe.

Comment: Hi Parthiban san, Thank you for your continuous support. I build with above option (added in local.conf). Build was successful but when I flashed it on board same error occurs. (lspci command not found) Even I am getting error for PCIe - PCIe link down. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: @user10561367: Do you have `ls /sbin/lspci` in your target?

Comment: no its not there. but bitbake -s | grep -i pciutils command shows the pciutils. Is there any other method to add lspci in bin or sbin?

Comment: If you have compiled the with `bitbake pciutils`, you can find the binary in `tmp/work/armXXX/pciutils/<VERSION>/image/` directory or `deploy-ipk/rpm` should have the package. You can manually copy this to target and try it.

Comment: Thank you I will try likewise.